# Rename image file in upload

Tags: php, file, upload

I am working on my upload file and I have trouble renaming the new file. Could you take a look and help me out?

Here is my script:

```
$fileName = $recipient . basename($sanitize_file);

$fileEX = substr($sanitize_file, strripos($fileName, '.'));

$now =time();

 while (file_exists($fileName)) {

 $fileName = $fileEX . $now;

 $now++;
}
```

When the file upload goes the fileFolder, it cannot be read as a file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Er...if you're trying to rename the file to the time, then the `$now` should go first, then the extension after??

```
$fileName = $now.$fileEX;

$now++;
```

Comment: The problem is that the image is not image anymore when it comes in the uplod folder...i want to add date to the new image upload.

Comment: Then what's the file extension when you bring it into your code?